# Finding three equal substrings of equal length

Tags: algorithm

Given a string S, I need to find three equal substrings of equal length.
Each of the three strings should not be overlapping. Also if three strings are A,B,C then S may not be A+B+C. Only condition to hold is A need to be prefix,B need to be in between and C need to be suffix.

What can be the maximum length of each string.

Example : Let string S="aaaaaa" then here answer is 2. How to solve this problem, please help. 
Explanation : Prefix side will be aa{1, 2}. Suffix side will be aa{6, 7} and Between part will be aa{3, 4} or aa{4, 5}.

Is there O(N) solution possible for this problem ? Or if not whats best complexity algorithm that can be proposed.

Comment: What if the string has length 10?

Comment: @timgeb It can be possible . Like say S=aaabaabaaa then here answer is 2. Prefix  {aa} for index 1 and 2, Between {aa} for index 5 and 6 and suffix {aa} for index 9 and 10

Comment: @timgeb then it will be 3. {aaa}

Comment: Since you are only interested in the theoretically maximum length - without testing if the strings are *actually* equal - then it sounds as simple as `floor(length/3)`.

Comment: @Jongware But it may not be true as string can have other characters from a-z

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem can be solved easily with a *prefix function*.

Consider the string `S[1 .. N]`. First of all, let's calculate a *prefix function*. After this step we have an array `P[1 .. N]`, where `P[i]` is the length of the largest suffix of substring `S[1 .. i]` that matches it's prefix, `P[i] < i`.

Then we just need to iterate over the whole string. For every `i`, `i = 2 .. N - 1` we assume that the middle string ends in position `i`.

In the same time `P[i]` is longest suffix of `S[1 .. i]` that matches it's prefix and `P[N]` is the longest suffix of `S[1 .. N]` that matches it's prefix.

Also note, that our substrings can't overlap. So for `S[1 .. i]` the length of the longest suffix that matches prefix and can be the required substring is `min(P[i], i / 2)`. For `S[1 .. N]` the length of the longest suffix that matches prefix and can be the required substring is limited by `min(P[N], N - i)`.

So for every `i`, `i = 2 .. N - 1` we can update the answer by `min(min(P[i], i / 2), min(P[N], N - i))` trying to get the maximum.

This solution has desired linear complexity.

For example, if examined string is `"aaaaaa"`, then `P` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

After that we try update the answer:

```
i = 2    min(min(1, 2 / 2), min(5, 6 - 2)) = 1
i = 3    min(min(2, 3 / 2), min(5, 6 - 3)) = 1
i = 4    min(min(3, 4 / 2), min(5, 6 - 4)) = 2
i = 5    min(min(4, 5 / 2), min(5, 6 - 5)) = 1
```

So, the answer is `2`.